# How to run bitcoin atom daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, server

I set up the [bitcoin atom daemon](https://github.com/bitcoin-atom/bitcoin-atom) on an Ubuntu server and I want to run it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is simply passing the `-daemon` flag not working?

Comment: No it's not working am running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? What happens instead, is there an error in the debug log?

Comment: I just followed the steps of installing btc atom and build it on Ubuntu . but i couldn't find any other steps related to how to configure rpc and how to run btc atom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may miss rpcport number in configuration file.

Run `nano ~/.bitcoinatom/atom.conf`

Add new line `rpcport=7332` for mainet or `rpcport=17332` for testnet

Kill the process and restart server

Ref: https://github.com/bitcoin-atom/bitcoin-atom/wiki/Mining-Instructions

Comment: How to run it again?

Comment: And what's the other information of RPC and from where i get it? like the ip address , the rpc user, rpc password ... etc

Comment: Sometimes  stop command may not work after configuration change. Then you have to kill the process using  pkill -9 -f [process name] command. Here process name is daemon server name.

Comment: Their wiki doesn't provide much informations. You can utilize the bitcoin core wiki as reference. https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpc-quick-reference . For rpc password and username, use any arbitrary string.

Comment: Does the configuration of btc atom goes same for BTC?
Like same RPC port ?

Comment: I checked the server and i found bitcoin.conf for bitcoin daemon which previous dev did . these are the lines in that file
server=1
rpcuser=btcuserpass
rpcpassword=btcpassworhuzehfsk
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.250.230.216
port=40443
server=1
deamon=1
txindex=1
prune=550
walletnotify=/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmqadmin publish routing_key=peatio.deposit.coin payload='{txid:%s, channel_key:satoshi}'

Comment: On other side the board is asking for URL+Port , RPC user and RPC password . so does it mean the information which i need is for URL and port will be like http://192.250.230.216:40443
Or something else because the ip address which is motioned on the config file is not the same ip address of the server which is running the bitcoin daemon

Comment: rpcallowip is to accept incoming rpc connections from outside the localhost. This is what u really wants?

Comment: yes i want to connect this daemon with a board on another server via rpc